# Another equivalent condition for being $T_1$−space $(X,\mathscr T)$ is normal.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, separation-axioms

A $T_1-$space  $(X,\mathscr T)$ is normal iff for each pair of disjoint closed subsets $C$ and $D$ of $X$ there are open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $C\subseteq U$, $D\subseteq V,$ and $\overline{U}\cap \overline{V}=\emptyset.$

**My attempt:-**

Proof. Suppose $T_1-$space  $(X,\mathscr T)$ is normal. for each pair of disjoint closed subsets $C$ and $D$ of $X.$  We know that $X\setminus C$ is an open set.  Additionally, we know that $D\subseteq X\setminus C$.By the [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3110177/an-equivalent-condition-for-being-t-1-space-x-mathscr-t-is-normal), there is and open set $V$ such that $D\subseteq V$ and $\overline V \subseteq X\setminus C$. Applying the same [theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3110177/an-equivalent-condition-for-being-t-1-space-x-mathscr-t-is-normal). We get another open set $W$ such that $D\subseteq W$ and $\overline W \subseteq X\setminus C.$ Hence, we get $C\subseteq X\setminus \overline V$. Let $U= X\setminus \overline V$. $C\subseteq X\setminus \overline W\implies D\subseteq \overline W \subseteq V. $

We have $\overline U\cap \overline W\subseteq \overline U\cap V= \overline{X\setminus \overline{V}}\cap V=\emptyset$.($\because$ $X\setminus   \overline{V} \subseteq X\setminus V$, $X\setminus V$ is closed so $\overline {X\setminus V}= X\setminus V)$. Hence $U$ and $W$ are the desired sets.

Conversely, Let $(X,\mathscr T)$ be a $T_1-$space,  for each pair of disjoint closed subsets $C$ and $D$ of $X$ there are open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $C\subseteq U$, $D\subseteq V,$ and $\overline{U}\cap \overline{V}=\emptyset.$ So,$U\cap V \subseteq \overline{U}\cap \overline{V}=\emptyset.$ By the definition of normal space, $T_1-$space  $(X,\mathscr T)$ is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly simpler put: If we can separate disjoint closed $C$ and $D$ with open sets with disjoint closures, then the open sets are already disjoint and we have normality.

On the other hand if we have normality and disjoint closed $C,D$ we apply normality thrice to get neighbourhoods with disjoint closure: once to get disjoint open $U_1,U_2$ separating $C$ and $D$. Then another time to find an intermediate $U$ with $C \subseteq U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq U_1$ and once more for $D$ and $U_2$ giving us an open $V$ with $D \subseteq V \subseteq \overline{V} \subseteq U_2$. Then the closures of $U$ and $V$ are disjoint as $U_1$ and $U_2$ are.

Remark: You cannot do this with Hausdorffness: the condition that distinct points have open neighbourhoods with disjoint closures is strictly stronger than Hausdorff.

Comment: Is my proof correct?

Comment: @Unknownx yes, in essence, but my version is simpler to read IMHO.

Comment: okay. Thank you.

Comment: Does there exist a simple example for normal is not hereditary? When I google it I got Tychonoff plank space. which is beyond my level :(

Comment: @Unknownx $D^2$ where $D$ is the so-called Double Arrow space is a compact Hausdorff space that contains the Sorgenfrey plane as a subspace.

Comment: @Unknownx a variation on that plank also works: take an uncountable discrete set and its one-point compacification $K$. Let $S$ be a convergent sequence with limit. Then $K \times S$ is compact Hausdorff and removing one point can leave us with a non-normal subspace.